# Flutter: How i can make List for messages?

Tags: flutter

I need to make a list of messages, I have this model

```
enum MessageType {sent, received}
class Messages {
  MessageType status;
  String contactName;
  String message;
  String time;

  Messages({ this.status, this.message, this.contactName, this.time});
}
```

And this way to make a list

```
 final response = await http.get(url);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      print(response.body);

      var allMessages = (json.decode(response.body) as Map)['messages'] as Map<String, dynamic>;

      var MessagesList = List<Messages>();

      allMessages.forEach((String key, dynamic val){
        var record = Messages(contactName: val['ownerName'], message: val['body'], time: '123', status: );
      });
```

I have two questions.

1. How can I substitute the value 'received' in status?

2.how to set received or sent depending on which id?

If id = 1, then put 'received', if other then put 'sent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this.
Convert your JSON to a List of Message using a custom "fromJson" method and, during the conversion, set the MessageType as needed.

```
enum MessageType { sent, received }

class Message {
  MessageType status;
  String contactName;
  String message;
  String time;

  Message({this.status, this.message, this.contactName, this.time});

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
        status: json["status"] == 1 ? MessageType.received : MessageType.sent,
        contactName: json["contactName"],
        message: json["message"],
        time: json["time"],
      );
}

Future<List<Message>> getMessage() async {
  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);

    List<Message> allMessages = List<Message>.from(
        json.decode(response.body).map((x) => Message.fromJson(x)));

    return allMessages;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a separate file that generates a bubble, how can I pass messages to it?
Here is the code that calls the file for render

`           
         itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                      if (messages[i]['status'] == MessageType.received) {
                        return ReceivedMessagesWidget(i: i);
                      } else {
                        return SentMessageWidget(i: i);
                      }
                    },
`

Comment: in receivedmessagewidget i have this 
`Text(

                "${messages[i]['contactName']}",

                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,

              ),
`

Comment: Hello @ike13 when you have a Message List you just need to access the property like this:  if (messages[i].status == MessageType.received)   or like this:   ${messages[i].contactName

Comment: @camilo777 How can I make an array of data from this data?

Comment: Check my sample.     List<Message> allMessages = List<Message>.from(
        json.decode(response.body).map((x) => Message.fromJson(x)));

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use an inline ternary operator like this: `testCondition ? trueValue : falseValue`

implemented in your code would look like this:

```
allMessages.forEach((String key, dynamic val){var record = Messages(
    contactName: val['ownerName'], 
    message: val['body'], 
    time: '123', 
    status: id==1 ? MessageType.received : MessageType.sent);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The name 'MessageType' is defined in the libraries ChatRoomsModel
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports

Comment: Ah, that is because you are importing a library that also has a class defined as 'MessageType'. When you run your code, the compiler doesn't know if you want the one you defined or the one in the ChatRoomsModel library. Either rename your enum, or import the ChatRoomsModel with a prefix, and reference it with the prefix.
Import like this: `Import 'package:chatroomsmodel/chatroomsmodel' as chat`
Use like this: chat.methodToAccess